# Identify $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty } x^2 \left(\sqrt{x^4+x+1}-\sqrt{x^4+x+5}\right)$

Tags: limits

> Identify $$\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty } x^2 \left(\sqrt{x^4+x+1}-\sqrt{x^4+x+5}\right)$$

My Try :

$$\sqrt{x^4+x+1}=\sqrt{x^4(1+\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{x^4})}=x^2\sqrt{(1+\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{x^4})}$$

Now : $$\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{x^4}=z$$

$$(1+z)^{\frac{1}{n}}= 1 + \frac1n x + \frac{1 - n}{2n^2}x^2 + \frac{2n^2 - 3n + 1}{6n^3}x^3 + O(x^4)$$
$$(1+(\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{x^4}))^{\frac{1}{2}}= 1 + \frac12 z - \frac{1}{8}z^2 + + O(z^3)$$

$$(1+(\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{x^4}))^{\frac{1}{2}}= 1 + \frac12 (\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{x^4}) - \frac{1}{8}(\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{x^4})^2 + O(z^3)$$

$$(1+(\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{x^4}))^{\frac{1}{2}}= 1 + \frac{1}{2x^3}+\frac{1}{2x^4} - \frac{x^2+2x+1}{8x^8} + O(z^3)$$

And :

$$\sqrt{x^4+x+1}=\sqrt{x^4(1+\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{5}{x^4})}=x^2\sqrt{(1+\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{5}{x^4})}$$

So :

$$(1+(\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{5}{x^4}))^{\frac{1}{2}}= 1 +  \frac{1}{2x^3}+\frac{5}{2x^4} -  \frac{x^2+10x+25}{8x^8}+ O(z^3)$$

$$\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty }=x^4( 1 + \frac{1}{2x^3}+\frac{1}{2x^4} - \frac{x^2+2x+1}{8x^8} + O(z^3)-( 1 +  \frac{1}{2x^3}+\frac{5}{2x^4} -  \frac{x^2+10x+25}{8x^8}+ O(z^3)))$$

$$\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty }=x^4(\frac{1}{2x^4}-\frac{5}{2x^4})=x^4(\frac{-4}{2x^4})=-2$$

is it right ?

Comment: Am I missing something?  It looks like the limit should be zero...

Comment: The expression is zero and thus the limit is zero...check carefully what you wrote.

Comment: @DonAntonio im sorry  .I edited

Comment: Ok, it looks correct.

Comment: This is very correct, for sure. If I may suggest, since you have the terms up to $O\left(\frac{1}{x^9}\right)$, you could continue and show that the expression is $-2+\frac  1 {x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)$ which, for sure, shows the limit but also how it is approached. Good job $\to +1$. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Write
\begin{align}
\sqrt{x^4+x+1}-\sqrt{x^4+x+5}
=\frac{(\sqrt{x^4+x+1}-\sqrt{x^4+x+5})(\sqrt{x^4+x+1}+\sqrt{x^4+x+5})}{\sqrt{x^4+x+1}+\sqrt{x^4+x+5}}
\end{align}
and use
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^4+x+5}}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^4+x+1}+\sqrt{x^4+x+5}}\leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^4+x+1}} 
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\sqrt{x^4+x+1}&=\sqrt{x^4(1+x^{-3}+x^{-4})}=x^2\sqrt{1+x^{-3}+x^{-4}}\\
\sqrt{x^4+x+5}&=\sqrt{x^4(1+x^{-3}+5x^{-4})}=x^2\sqrt{1+x^{-3}+5x^{-4}}
\end{align}

Comment: The OP's question is whether their **approach** is sound, not how to compute the limit.

Comment: @Did An 11 line approach to what can be done in one line is obviously not sound, although maybe (who cares?) correct.

Comment: @uniquesolution Maybe he wants to do it by this method, he previously asked http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2211574/what-is-binomial-series-of-1z-frac1n-1-frac1nzoz2.

Comment: @uniquesolution This is *obviously* quite short-sighted. If you compare the two approaches to solve the question, one (to multiply by the conjugate quantity) is anecdotal (and short) while the other (limited expansions) is hugely important in the whole domain of analysis (and yes, longer in the present case). You might want to think again... (And anyway, the OP asked for the soundness of their approach, not for the limit itself, didn't they?)

Comment: His approach is not very good, so i decided to give him a better one. In addition, the given problem was wrong and was edited after DonAntonio remarked, he should check what he wrote. I already thougt that he had made an mistake.

Comment: @Did I disagree.

Comment: @uniquesolution OK. Care to elaborate? You know, with arguments and all that...

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(x^2\:\left(\sqrt{x^4+x+1}-\sqrt{x^4+x+5}\right)\right)
& = \lim _{x\to \infty }\left(-\frac{4x^2}{\sqrt{x^4+x+1}+\sqrt{x^4+x+5}}\right)
\\& = \lim _{x\to \infty }\left(-\frac{4x^2}{x^2\sqrt{1+\frac{x}{x^4}+\frac{1}{x^4}}+x^2\sqrt{1+\frac{x}{x^4}+\frac{5}{x^4}}}\right)
\\& \approx_\infty \lim _{x\to \infty }\left(-\frac{4x^2}{2x^2}\right)
\\& = \color{red}{-2}
\end{aligned}
$$

In this case you can solve it with just an approximation without using the Taylor expansion, anyway your procedure is right.